# the king of England is more generous than any other ones of France

Tags: pronouns, single-word-requests

I heard that in N-bar system, a pronoun "one" only substitutes for N-bar thing, not just a noun.

So in the following sentence, should "ones" be changed into "kings"?

> The king of England is more generous than any other ones of France.

And if yes, I found another sentence below:

> "An Italian version by John Florio, the Elizabethan translator of Montaigne, still remains in manuscript, as does a Spanish one made by John Pemberton of London in the early years of the seventeenth century"

In 'as does a Spanish one', 'one' substitutes for the word 'version'. Even though version is a just noun and the N-bar is 'Italian version', so how 'one' can substitute for a noun, not N-bar in this case?

Comment: Leaving this as a comment because it isn't the main point of your question: it sounds wrong to have *both* "other" and "of France". The king of England is not a king of France, so they can't be "other" kings of France. You should use as your example either "than any other kings" or "than the kings of France".

Comment: I've never heard of 'the N-bar system' and Googling it finds nothing relevant. In my experience, 'one' substitutes for a noun that has just been mentioned. I agree with Sumelic's comment.

Comment: @KateBunting I suppose the first *N-bar* should be *X-bar*; in [X-bar theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-bar_theory) an "N-bar" (originally N marked with a stroke over it, subsequently with a prime: N′) represents the constituent consisting of a noun with its modifiers but without its determiner.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) may be of some interest.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your first example, sumelic and Kate Bunting point out that *any other ones of France* is not felicitous: *other* improperly puts *the king of England* and *the ones of France* in the same category. In any case, use of *ones* here is unlikely; depending on what you mean we would most likely say either

> The king of England is more generous than any other—*for instance, {those / the kings} of France*, or
>   The king of England is more generous than any (king) of France.

With respect to your second example, note two points:

- An N′ may be realized as a bare noun or pronoun.
- An N′ may be embedded in another N′.

You may thus rescue X-bar theory by parsing both *version* and its parallel *one* as embedded N-bars—which you pretty much have to do anyway, to preserve the parallelism and constrast of their respective modifiers.

Alternatively, you may redefine your understanding of *one* and say that it may represent either an N-bar or an N.

Comment: Substituting "one" for an N' is not coreferential anaphora, since N' do not refer.  NPs may refer, not N'.  Substituting "one" is identity of sense anaphora, not identity of reference.

Comment: @GregLee Ah -- that is a subtle distinction I had not known before--but it's obvious when you say it. Thank you! ... Will striking the word *co-referent*, as I have now done, make the answer sound?

Comment: Looks ok to me.